# Write multi list in dict pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, save

I try to parse site and have this problem. I'm sure that maximum number of images of each goods is 7. Each image link write to list. And then save it in Excel. So each link have the column like in file 1.xlsx. But there are some goods that have 3 or 5 images. So if the number of images is less than 7, I want to fill the another field with empty string. But I get the result like in file 2.xlsx.

Please, help me to fix that problem.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from time import sleep
import time, csv
from csv import reader
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import requests, json


def get_html(url):
    headers={
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
        }
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content
    return r

goods_link = ['https://www.johnlewis.com/a-a-k-s-hana-raffia-cross-body-bag-navy-multi/p5559710']


Images1 = []
Images2 = []
Images3 = []
Images4 = []
Images5 = []
Images6 = []
Images7 = []
Img = []

for i in goods_link:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(get_html(i), 'html.parser')

    imgContainer = soup.find('div', {'class':'ProductImages_productImagesContainer__1v2kP'})
    imgAll = imgContainer.find_all('div', {'class':'ImageMagnifier_zoomable-image-container__db7jH'})
    for j in imgAll:
        imgSrc = j.find('img').get('src').split('?$rsp')[0]
        Img.append(imgSrc)

    [x.append(y) for x,y in zip([Images1, Images2, Images3, Images4, Images5, Images6, Images7], Img)]

info = {}


for ii in Images1:
    info.setdefault('Images1',[])
    info['Images1'].append(ii)
for ii in Images2:
    info.setdefault('Images2',[])
    info['Images2'].append(ii)
for ii in Images3:
    info.setdefault('Images3',[])
    info['Images3'].append(ii)
for ii in Images4:
    info.setdefault('Images4',[])
    info['Images4'].append(ii)
for ii in Images5:
    info.setdefault('Images5',[])
    info['Images5'].append(ii)
for ii in Images6:
    info.setdefault('Images6',[])
    info['Images6'].append(ii)
for ii in Images7:
    info.setdefault('Images7',[])
    info['Images7'].append(ii)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(info)
df.to_excel('./output.xlsx')

print('Finish')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you want to fill all 7 columns for each row, even if this row has less than 7 images.
The step of creating a dictionary is superflous. You can list all you images in lists that you append in a list of lists and create your DataFrame from it.
You can specify the headers with `columns=`:

```
def get_html(url):
    headers={
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
        }
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers).content
    return r

goods_link = ['https://www.johnlewis.com/a-a-k-s-hana-raffia-cross-body-bag-navy-multi/p5559710']


headers = ["Images1", "Images2", "Images3", "Images4", "Images5", "Images6", "Images7"]
img_table = []

for link in goods_link:
    img_row = [None]*7
    soup = BeautifulSoup(get_html(link), 'html.parser')

    imgContainer = soup.find('div', {'class':'ProductImages_productImagesContainer__1v2kP'})
    imgAll = imgContainer.find_all('div', {'class':'ImageMagnifier_zoomable-image-container__db7jH'})
    for j, div_obj in enumerate(imgAll):
        imgSrc = div_obj.find('img').get('src').split('?$rsp')[0]
        img_row[j]=imgSrc

    img_table.append(img_row)   

df = pd.DataFrame(img_table, columns=headers)
df.to_excel('./output.xlsx')

print('Finish')
```

What was missing was to create a list of `None` with length 7, then using `enumerate` to replace the element at index `j` with the corresponding link.

Please try to name your variables in a way that makes the code easier to understand next time.